# Compressing files from SCP on the fly

Tags: windows, ssh, scp

I am retrieving a large files using SCP (from a linux system to a Windows system), now is there any way of compressing that destination file on the fly, for example:

```
pscp -C root@123.123.123.123:/backups/backup1.bin Backups\backupdestination.bin
```

So "backupdestination.bin" would be compressed on the destination drive on the fly.

e.g. C:\backups\backupdestination.zip rather than C:\backups\backupdestination.bin

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest `rsync`, since it has a built in compression flag.

From the rsync man page (http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

```
-z, --compress              compress file data during the transfer
 --compress-level=NUM    explicitly set compression level
```

Comment: OP wants to compress the destination file, not the transfer

Answer (score 1):

Don't use scp, use ssh :)

The target machine can then "catch" the data. For your example:

```
ssh root@123.123.123.123 "cat /backups/backup1.bin"|gzip -9 -|Backups\backupdestination.bin
```

This whole scheme will work with anything that can take a contiguous stream of data from `stdin` and then process it. I'm not aware - off-hand - of a tool that creates ZIP files this way, though. In particular because ZIP files contain the meta-data such as file name and timestamp.

Comment: Hello, The only issue is that the command is being run from a windows machine :(

Comment: Which command? The inner `cat` or the out `ssh`? I think PuTTY should be able to deal with it. And even if it's not you can still use Cygwin or MinGW to achieve the goal. Basically, keep in mind that on the (source) machine (in your case) SFTP is only a subsystem to SSH. So if you'd provide a convenient subsystem on that machine to compress already before the data is sent, this could work around the limitations as well.

Comment: @afrazier: `pscp` is from PuTTY, so he's using it already.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a re-read to catch that.  7-Zip can handle stdin/stdout redirection if it needs to be done from the Windows system too, and can handle gzip/bzip2, if he doesn't want to use lzma.